# Angular2 Error while installing directive

Tags: angular

i'm trying to get familiar with Ang2. I'm following some tutorial which says i should add an directive with the command "ng g d NAME". Now when i'm doing this i get an Error:

installing directive:

- create src\app\highlight.directive.spec.ts
- create src\app\highlight.directive.ts

  ```
  Cannot read property 'read' of undefined
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'read' of undefined
     at InsertChange.apply (c:\Users\...\Desktop\Tutorials\Angular2\udemy\02-directives\node_modules\@angular-cli\ast-tools\src\change.js:96:20)
     at c:\Users\...\Desktop\Tutorials\Angular2\udemy\02-directives\node_modules\@angular-cli\ast-tools\src\change.js:71:61  
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
  ```

I don't know what to do, to fix this problem. The .ts file got created but i can't use the directive in my component.

Any suggestions are realy welcome.

Comment: I'm having the same error at the same file `change.js` on Mac. I'm doing a tutorial on udemy learning Angular 2. What I noticed is that my files are created, however, they don't automatically get integrated into the proper places in other files and I never get an `index.ts` in my folders either. I'm using `ng g c someComponent`. Doesn't matter if I do `--flat` or not.

Comment: I also went ahead and attempted to update the angular-cli to see if that would resolve the issue. It did not.

Comment: Are you doing this "Angular 2 - The Complete Guide" tutorial? I did update everthing related to the project. Did not work.

Comment: Yes I am... interesting that it's both happening on the same tutorial... Have you asked there? I'm going to go peek, if you haven't. I'm going to post the link to here. Next comment will have my error.

Comment: Error:
    `$ ng g c test
    installing component
      create src/app/test/test.component.css
      create src/app/test/test.component.html
      create src/app/test/test.component.spec.ts
      create src/app/test/test.component.ts
    Cannot read property 'read' of undefined
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'read' of undefined
        at InsertChange.apply (/recipe-book/node_modules/@angular-cli/ast-tools/src/change.js:96:20)
        at /recipe-book/node_modules/@angular-cli/ast-tools/src/change.js:71:61
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)`

Comment: I already did ask there but have no answer until now. 

In terms of the index.ts, i think with the release version of ang2 you only have one index.ts in the root directory and not in every single folder.

Comment: Well even if it's only in the root folder, it's not getting all my new components and such. I went ahead and posted my same issue there as well as my findings thus far. (I'm the response there sorry!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer @MrJuliuss but with full steps and details... Steps below are for global installation. To make it simply for local remove the `-g` from the `npm` commands.

1. Run `ng -v` to see what version you have.

   ```
   angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
   node: 6.5.0
   os: darwin x64
   ```
2. Get the latest version of Node: https://nodejs.org/
3. Uninstall the `beta.15` (anything less than 16)

   ```
   npm uninstall -g angular-cli
   ```
4. Clean the cache

   ```
   npm cache clean
   ```
5. Re-install the new latest version

   ```
   npm install -g angular-cli@latest
   ```
6. Create a new project with the new CLI. You can copy/paste your code files to the new project. The old project will not allow the new CLI to work. (Which is what continues to lead me to believe this was a permissions issue.

   ```
   ng new <project-name>
   ```

Comment: Thanks you all. The last answer fixed my Problem!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.15 and fixed it with 1.0.0-beta.16

- `npm install -g angular-cli` to update your global ng cli
- I modify my package.json project with `1.0.0-beta.16`(devDependencies) instead of `1.0.0-beta.15`
- `npm install` in the project

And it works.

Comment: Please list the steps you did to complete this upgrade. I used `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` then `npm cache clean` finally `npm install -g angular-cli@latest` also ... what version of node? I'm using 6.5.

Comment: Thanks! I had started writing a full post and provided a few more details, so I finished it as seen below. :)